# Address and open a bootstrap accordion via an anchor link

Tags: html, css, accordion

here is what I would like to implement:

I am using **Bootstrap v3.4.1** for a project and have **two columns side by side**. I would like to use the **links** in the hotspot banner (left column) to address the associated Accordions (right column) and also open them directly.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be realized?

In the left column I have a hotspot banner:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <section class="hotspots--wrapper"> 
      <img src="/images/produktbeschreibung/wheel-585x.png" alt="" class="hotspots--figure"> 
          <a class="hotspot hotspot--harz" href="#"> 
              <span class="hotspot--title hotspot--title__right">Harz</span> 
              <span class="hotspot--cta"></span> </a> 
          <a class="hotspot hotspot--felge" href="#collapse3"> 
              <span class="hotspot--title">Felge</span> 
              <span class="hotspot--cta"></span> </a> 
          <a class="hotspot hotspot--speichen" href="#"> 
              <span class="hotspot--title hotspot--title__right">Speichen</span> 
              <span class="hotspot--cta"></span> </a> 
          <a class="hotspot hotspot--nabe" href="#"> 
              <span class="hotspot--title hotspot--title__right">Nabe</span> 
              <span class="hotspot--cta"></span> </a> 
  </section>
</div>
```

In the right column I have a Bootstrap Accordion:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading1" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Harz</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading2" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Felge</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse2" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading3" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Speichen</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse3" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading4" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Name</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse4" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2"` to the links to open `#collapse2`. In order to prevent `hashchange` event firing, you can change the `<a>` element to another tag, for example '`

```css
.btn-link {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <section class="hotspots--wrapper">
    <img src="/images/produktbeschreibung/wheel-585x.png" alt="" class="hotspots--figure">
    <span class="hotspot hotspot--harz btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
      <span class="hotspot--title hotspot--title__right">Harz</span>
    <span class="hotspot--cta"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="hotspot hotspot--felge btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
      <span class="hotspot--title">Felge</span>
    <span class="hotspot--cta"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="hotspot hotspot--speichen btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
      <span class="hotspot--title hotspot--title__right">Speichen</span>
    <span class="hotspot--cta"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="hotspot hotspot--nabe btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">
      <span class="hotspot--title hotspot--title__right">Nabe</span>
    <span class="hotspot--cta"></span>
    </span>
  </section>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading1" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Harz</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading2" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Felge</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse2" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading3" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse3" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Speichen</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse3" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="faq-panel-heading" id="heading4" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button class="btn btn-block faq collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse4" style="text-align:left; white-space:normal;" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Name</button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="faq panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse4" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work relatively well. In principle. In a Gambio store, where I'm trying to implement this, unfortunately not.

If the accordion associated with the link is closed, the page scrolls to the top, that accordion remains closed.

When the accordion associated with the link is open, the page scrolls to the panel title. --> Link: https://www.bike-laufrad.de/equator-50c.html --> Described behavior can be tested relatively far down under "Technology".

Comment: No problem, I modified my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Accordion function has disappeared. Now the individual panels no longer close when you open another one.

Comment: Fixed. Added `data-parent="#accordion"`

Comment: Perfect. I spent hours trying to find a solution until you answered me here. Actually, the implementation was relatively simple, shame on me.
Thank you so much!!!